# Add NavigationController in class not in appdelegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

how to add the navigationcontroller in `viewDidLoad` method of any class for their next class, i have not added it in the starting in appdelegate .

Answer (score 2):

```
YourViewController *report = [[YourViewController alloc]  init]; // create Object of YourViewController

UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:report]; // add YourViewController as root view controller of UINavigationController

[self presentModalViewController:navigationController animated:YES];
```

Comment: if they Not adding NavigationController at appDelegate How to push it..?

Comment: hello, i need one help, please ,other concept for same task, i move from view coontroller to 2nd view using presentviewcontroller method, than on 2nd view i have button method to get back on viewcontroller how i writ code for this,..thanks in advance

Comment: @Youaregreat- write in button method [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];